# how to calling get_data function in this code

Tags: python, function, class

i am new to work with python and i want to run this code ,

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
from torch_geometric.data import DataLoader

class Preprocess():
    def __init__(self, config, d_name):
       self.root_dir = config.root_dir
       self.batch_size = config.batch_size
    
       self.cora = Planetoid(root='./data/cora', name='Cora')
       #self.citeseer = Planetoid(root='./data/citeseer', name='CiteSeer')
       #self.pubmed = Planetoid(root='./data/pubmed', name='PubMed')
    
       self.num_classes, self.num_node_features, self.data = self.get_data(d_name)
    
    def get_data(self, d_name):
        '''
        d_name = 'Cora', 'CiteSeer', 'PubMed'
        '''
        dataset = Planetoid(root=self.root_dir + d_name , name=d_name)
    
        return dataset.num_classes, dataset.num_node_features, DataLoader(dataset, batch_size 
        = self.batch_size)
f=Preprocess(config, Cora)
f.get_data(Cora)
```

but get this error: name 'config' is not defined

Comment: In the given code you never initialize or import any value called `config`

Comment: `class config():  `
    `#Preprocess`
   ` root_dir = ./data/`
   ` batch_size = 1`
    
   ` #Model`
    `hidden_dim = 16 `
   ` dropout_rate = 0.5`
   ` l2_reg = 5*10e-4`
    
   ` #Train`
   ` learning_rate = 0.01`
    `epochs = 200`
    `loss_type = 'cross_entropy' # or nll_loss` @joshmeranda

Answer (score 0):

So, It is not a bug.

Look your constructor:

```
def __init__(self, config, d_name): 
    self.root_dir = config.root_dir 
    self.batch_size = config.batch_size 
    
    etc...
```

And your instantiation:

```
f = Preprocess(config, Cora) 
f.get_data(Cora)
```

Note that you are passing a variable "config" that has not been declared before. Also, by the arg "config" type in the constructor, yout need pass an object as a parameter to the instantiation "f = Preprocess(args)", because the arg "config" needs to have an "root_dir" atribute.

Please, check the Pytorch documentation for more examples of how to use this framework. Don't give up, you can do it.